# putting an object into a vector, undefined identifier

Tags: c++, oop

I'm relatively new to c++. I'm trying to create a graph class. I try to create a vector of the vertexes in the graph constructor but I'm getting an undefined identifier error when I call Vector.push_back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Graph {
public: Graph(int vertexNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexNum - 1; i++)
        Vertex vert(i);
        this->vertexList.push_back(vert);
    }
    private:
    class Vertex {
        public: 
        Vertex(int vertexId) {
            this->vertId = vertexId;
        }
        int vertId;
    };


    std::vector<Vertex> vertexList;
};
```

I'm sure there are other logic errors in the code that I haven't fixed yet, I'm still working on it, but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong with the vector.

Here are the error discriptions:

identifier "vert" is undefined  dijkstra    main.cpp    9
'vert': undeclared identifier   dijkstra main.cpp   9

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also show use the *actual* errors, copy-pasted as text, complete and without modifications.

Comment: If you have several errors, always start with solving the first one. C++ errors have a tendency to cause cascades of other errors that are side effects of the first.

Comment: In which part of your code are you trying to call the `Vector.push_back()` function ? and how are you calling it ? with which parameter ? there can be a lot of reason to get a undefined identifier error. Could you show us more of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ before you can use a variable you need to declare it even in class definitions, simply moving the declaration of the std::vector above the constructor where it is used will resolve that error. This is why people typically create a header for the class, so that all declaration is done in it and the .cpp contains the implementation. Similarly you'd need to do the same for the vertex class and edge class. Also, the Graph implementation depends on the existence of the Vertex class, so the Vertex class needs to be declared and implemented before the Graph implementation.  Also, more importantly you forgot to put braces around the for loop which is the main problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
   class Graph {
        private:
        class Vertex {
            public: 
            int vertId;
            Vertex(int vertexId) {
                this->vertId = vertexId;
            }

        };

        class Edge {
            public:
                Vertex* start;
                Vertex* end;
                int weight;
                Edge(Vertex* start, Vertex* end, int weight) {
                    this->start = start;
                    this->end = end;
                    this->weight = weight;
                }

        };

        public:
        std::vector<Vertex> vertexList; 
        Graph(int vertexNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexNum - 1; i++) {
            Vertex vert(i);
            this->vertexList.push_back(vert);
           }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you were right, the braces fixed the problem. I've been writing a lot of python lately and it totally slipped my mind. should I break Vertex and Edge into separate classes, or would splitting Graph into .h and.cpp work?

Comment: Splitting the class into h and cpp makes the code easier to read, and if you don't split them up, if you include this class multiple times in other object files you will get the Multiple definition errors during compilation. So best practice is to split it up to avoid this. Can I get a up vote there ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where indentation is important. You don't have braces in your for loop, so its understood like

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertexNum - 1; i++) {
    Vertex vert(i);
}
this->vertexList.push_back(vert);
```

Where it now makes sense that `vert` is not defined.